# Splitting a delimited file and storing into new column

Tags: python, split

I am trying to split csv file. After reading the delimited file, I want to split desired column furthur. My sample code:

```
import csv
sample = open('~/sample.txt')
adr = csv.reader(sample, delimiter='|')
for row in adr:
    a = row[0]
    b = row[1]
    c = row[2]
    d = row [3]
    new=""
    new = row[4].split(",")
    for row1 in new:
        print row1
```

sample.txt file contains:

```
aa|bb|cc|dd|1,2,3,4|xx
ab|ax|am|ef|1,5,6|jk
cx|kd|rd|j|1,9|k
```

Above code produce output as:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[1,5,6]
[1,9]
```

I am trying to further split new column and going to use splited output for comparison. For example, desired output for splitting will be :

```
aa|bb|cc|dd|1|2|3|4|xx
ab|ax|am|ef|1|5|6| |jk
cx|kd|rd|j|1|9| | |k
```

Also I want to store mutiple blank or NULL value of new column, as shown in above example [1,2,3,4], [1,5,6]. Is there better way to split?

Comment: So the row with the most sub-columns is always the first one? Otherwise how does one determine the number of blanks or NULLs to add when processing the other rows of the input file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty much there already! A few more lines after `new = row[4].split(",")` are all you need.

```
for i in range(len(new), 4):
    new.append('')
newrow = row[0:4] + new + row[5:]
print('|'.join(newrow))
```

Edit 2: addressing your comments below in the simplest way possible, just loop through it twice, looking for the longest "subarray" the first time. Re: printing extra times, you likely copied the code into the wrong place/indentation and have it in the loop.

Full code:

```
import csv
sample = open('~/sample.txt')
adr = csv.reader(sample, delimiter='|')
longest = 0
for row in adr:
    curLen = len(row[4].split(','))
    if curLen > longest:
        longest = curLen

sample.seek(0)
for row in adr:
    new = row[4].split(",")
    for i in range(len(new), longest):
        new.append(' ')
    newrow = row[0:4] + new + row[5:]
    print('|'.join(newrow))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one doubt, there might be n number new column, for example [1,2,3,4] or [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] etc. can we fix for multiple columns? One more thing, present code gives t times repetitive output.

Comment: Updated it to look for the longest one since that seems to be what you want.

Comment: Thanks bbil for help :) .. can we store joined rows into csv file?

Comment: The docs for python csv https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html are great. It's as simple as `w = csv.writer(openfile, delimiter='|'); w.writerow(newrow)`